# Do fruit trees only ever drop fruit, even if there was no fruit to be picked that day?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have read a few places that this is the case but I just want to clarify that this is not only for days where there is fruit on the tree.

Day 1: Pear tree has 3 pears on it. I pick the pears. Obviously I can shake it a million more times and I will get nothing else.

Day 2: The same tree. There are no pears to pick because I picked them on Day 1. Is this still guaranteed to give me nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean "will fruit trees drop money, bees or furniture" then no, fruit frees will never drop any items other than fruit. Only Oak and Spruce trees will ever drop bells/bees/furniture leaves.